# Python commands.getstatusoutput() returning 0 even though the command failed

Tags: python, informix, python-2.6

I am executing the informix ontape command for backup via the Python `commands.getstatusoutput()` function call.

Example:

```
(rc, op) = commands.getstatusoutput("ontape -v -s -L 1|compress -c >/home/compressed/level_1_archive")
```

After executing the above function, the return code rc is 0
and the output message op is `"Archive failed - ISAM error:  An error has occurred during archive back up."`

What I don't understand is why is Python returning 0 even though the command failed

Python version used is 2.6.6

Comment: What do you get when you execute the command in shell and then you give the command `echo $?`? Just curious to see what the error code in shell is.

Comment: You should check the exit code of `ontape` is (see jakekimds' comment) -- if it doesn't return a nonzero exit code, you might consider using the `subprocess` module and piping stderr, then reading it with `communicate` -- depending on how `ontape` operates, it may be a reasonable fallback method for determining whether an error occured.  (And in either case, you should consider switching to `subprocess` anyway -- `commands` has been deprecated since 2.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not at the Python side. The output of the ontape command is piped to the gzip command. The exit code returned to the shell is the return code of the gzip command. Gzip command does not error out even though it receives no data from the ontape command and returns zero as exit code.

A couple of possible  resolutions for the issue are:

1. Use BACKUP_FILTER in the Informix onconfig file
2. Don't pipe the output of ontape to gzip; instead use something like this:

   ```
   "(rc, op) = commands.getstatusoutput("source /source ; ontape -v -s -L 0 -t STDIO | /bin/gzip ; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} > /backup/ontape_backup.gz")"
   ```

Comment: I think that you need to tweak the shell script a little.  The redirection probably needs to come before the `exit`.